# Create JSON on web server, Parse using jQuery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json

The following java code generates a simple JSON.

```
    Email rem = new Reminder("gidutz", Calendar.getInstance(), duedate,
            "someOne", "title the title", "data", "sender");


    JSONObject email = new JSONObject();
    email.put("id", rem.getId());
    email.put("title", rem.getTitle());
    email.put("creattion_date", creation);
    email.put("due_date", creation);
    email.put("creattion_date", due);

    try {
        ServerSocket sc = new ServerSocket(8082);
        while (true) {
            Socket client = sc.accept();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());

            out.print("HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + CRLF);
            out.print("Content-type: application/json" + CRLF);
            out.print(CRLF);
            out.print(email.toString());
            out.print(CRLF);
            out.flush();
            client.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I access via browser `localhost:8082` the following JSON shows:

> {"id":513097,"title":"title the
>   title","due_date":"2014-01-03-15-01","creattion_date":"2014-01-04-15-01"}

The following html page should parse the JSON

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script>
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8082', function(data) {
       alert(data);
    });
</script>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

However, no alert is showing.
any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Do you get some error reporting in your developer tools? (firebug or something)

Comment: unless the html page is also served on port 8082 you are most likely suffering from a [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issue

Comment: Vincent, yes i get JSON.parse unexpected end of data, when i surf from the browser the response is ok (no error)